# Cocoa: How to integrate swiftUI into cocoa project

Tags: swift, cocoa, swiftui

How can I add in a SwiftUI cocoa project?

For UIKit i must do this

```
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

What the equivalent for Cocoa?

Comment: Replace `UI` with `NS`

Comment: It's unresolved, I have to make an import? In my import I have only cocoa

Comment: You must `import SwiftUI` to use `NSHostingController`.

Comment: You have to `import SwiftUI`

Comment: UIHostingController is not available in Cocoa